# Deleting documents in multiple indices from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to delete all documents of a certain type across multiple indices (documents are created by logstash so there is an index for each day).

I've tried this:

```
DELETE _all/_query?q=type:iss
```

The result looks something like:

```
{
   "_indices": {
      "logstash-2014.01.18": {
         "_shards": {
            "total": 5,
            "successful": 0,
            "failed": 5
         }
      },
   "_indices": {
      "logstash-2014.01.18": {
         "_shards": {
            "total": 5,
            "successful": 2,
            "failed": 3
         }
      },
     ...
}
```

Every time I run it I get a different number of successes/failures in each index.  The 1st query above initially seemed to work.  If I look in elasticsearch-head and Kibana it seems like at least some of the documents have been deleted.  However if I then query for them:

```
POST _search {"query":{"match":{"type":"iis"}}}
```

or

```
GET _search?q=type:iis
```

it still returns all results.  I don't believe this is a caching problem as I've done everything possible to try to ensure that isn't the case (cleared browser data, restarted elasticsearch/server etc).

I also tried:

```
DELETE _all/iis/_query {"query":{"match_all":{}}}
```

Again I get the inconsistent success/failure results but it does seem to have deleted documents when I run the search queries again.  It only seems to be deleting a few every time though.

Why is this so inconsistent and what can I do to get this working consistently?

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to look into the bulk API to achieve this: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html ?

Comment: perhaps but with less than 400 documents to be deleted it doesn't seem like it should be needed.

Comment: I would suggest that, when creating an index with that type, you give them an alias. Then, you can delete by query using said alias. (aliases are really usefull when planning ahead). You can dynamically add new aliases to an old index, too.